# How to most efficiently generate an array based on collapsed values in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

Assume you have `listA`, and a defined array of "columns":

```
var listA = [{
    name: "Mike",
    exercisedateandtime: 1299233593000,
    exercise: "Jumping Jacks",
    numsets: 5
}, {
    name: "Charles",
    exercisedateandtime: 1299233593000,
    exercise: "Swimming",
    numsets: 2
}, {
    name: "Charles",
    exercisedateandtime: 1299233593000,
    exercise: "Swimming",
    numsets: 6
}, {
    name: "Mike",
    exercisedateandtime: 1299237012000,
    exercise: "Running",
    numsets: 5
}, {
    name: "William",
    exercisedateandtime: 1299237320000,
    exercise: "Fishing",
    numsets: 2
}, {
    name: "William",
    exercisedateandtime: 1299237611000,
    exercise: "Motor Boating",
    numsets: 6
}, {
    name: "Charles",
    exercisedateandtime: 1299237611000,
    exercise: "Swimming",
    numsets: 4
}];

var columns = ["Exercise Date", "Mike", "Charles", "William"]
```

The goal is to generate a single array from list A such that any times that happen to match up will be "collapsed". In this case, the output should be:

```
var output = [[1299233593000, 5, 2, null]
[1299237012000, 6, null, null]
[1299237012000, 6, null, 0]
[1299237320000, null, null, 2]
[1299237320000, null, null, 2]
[1299237611000, null, 4, 6]]
```

Notice how when one or more people have the same time "1299233593000", the "output" accounts for it and "collapses" them into a single array. Null values show up for the `exercisedatetimes` where an individual did not have any "numsets". The values that are not null are those where the individual has "numsets" for that time.

What is the best way to get to "output" using JavaScript while allowing variable names (say Fred was thrown in with his information into listA) and variable columns (assuming you could remove "William" from the "columns" array and it would not show up in the output).

Ideal solution would be best performance in speed and processing required.

Comment: What did you try, and where did you get stuck? And where do the `null` values come from, and the `na` (is that meant to be a string)?

Comment: For normal day to day small computations, any way is most efficient way.  Unless you are seeing performance issue, there is generally no need to optimize.  So, first solve it and then if you face a performance problem, you should ask the forum to help in finding a "most efficient" alternative.

Comment: Matching times are not really collapsed into a single row in your example. Either the problem description and your output example seem to be misaligned.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Sorry, misread your question. This doesn't really do what you want -- It doesn't take the names into account.  But it is still not fully clear to me what the problem exactly is.

The trick with this kind of problem usually is to keep a map (or nested maps) of the information you have collected so far, and to update it as needed. The map key usually should be the information you need to merge, so the lookup is efficient.

I haven't tested the code, it should just collapse the objects into rows. Depending on what your problem really is, it may or may not be a reasonable starting point.

The code puts labels into row 0 of the result, but it should be easy to add support for a predefined list as a starting point...

```
function collapse (array) {
  var labels = [];
  var result = [labels];
  var labelMap = 0;
  var timeMap = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var row = [];
    var entry = array[i];
    var time = entry.exercisedateandtime;
    var row = timeMap[time];
    if (row == null) {
      row = [];
      timeMap[time] = row;
      result.push(row);
    }
    for (var key in entry) {
      var index = labelMap[key];
      if (index == null) {
        index = labels.length;
        labels.push(key);
        labelMap[key] = index;
      }
      row[index] = entry[key];
    }
  }
  return result;    
}
```